# Nativescript cannot remove file during building

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

I have a problem with building an android app with native script and firebase. The error looks like:

```
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: rm: could not remove file (code EBUSY): D:/project-m00607281/platforms/android/app/google-services.json.
```

I don't know should I do, Can anyone can help me. If something more is needed just let me know.

Thank you in advice

Comment: Did you go through firebase plugin's setup instructions? Have you placed `google-services.json` in your `App_Resources/Android` folder?

Comment: Yes i did everything from instruction

Comment: It says `rm could not remove file`, may be a permission issue.